# Oracle Reports Builder: Unable to add new column

Tags: oraclereports

I am new to oracle reports builder. I have an existing report and I need to add new column into that report. But when I add new column old columns are disappearing. And moreover I am unable to see all the columns in (Report wizard -> label) tab. Please help me.

Comment: you should explain more about your problem, with screen shots, how did you try to add columns ? is it db column ? or formula ? or Summarized ?

Comment: I have got answer that i need to create column formula and column summary so that i can add that fields in pagelayout. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I have got answer that i need to create column formula and column summary so that i can add that fields in pagelayout. Thank you.